# Возможно ли такое оформление перечня?

Tags: перечисление

Я попытаюсь наметить ряд основных принципов.
1. Итак, первый принцип – это положение...
2. Вторым принципом выступает...
3. Третий принцип напрямую следует из предыдущего...
Возможно ли такое оформление перечня? Или нумерацию лучше убрать?

Comment: Слово "итак" в п.1 явно лишнее. Его нужно или убрать, или вынести из перечня наружу.

Comment: Уточнение: строки перечня это целые абзацы публицистического  текста.

Comment: Тогда лучше совсем убрать "итак". Или я не понимаю, какой смысл Вы в него вкладываете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если эта нумерация в дальнейшем тексте не используется, то её лучше убрать. Даже если используется, лучше её будет всюду по тексту заменить на "первый принцип, второй...".

Если Важно особо подчеркнуть номера этих пунктов (например, когда они слишком обширны — по нескольку страниц), я бы предложил использовать другое выделение (например, нумерацию римскими цифрами), чтобы это меньше напоминало обычный перечень.

Comment: Используется в том смысле, что иногда в тексте ссылаются на номера принципов, и в конце резюмируется, что перечислили шесть принципов того-то и того-то...

Comment: @Рад Если нумерация принципов совпадает с их порядковыми "именами", тогда это выглядит избыточно.

Answer (score 1):

Перечень оформляется более строго и чётко. Перед перечнем вы уже использовали слово ПРИНЦИПЫ, поэтому далее это слово можно не употреблять. Если используете цифры, после точки сразу излагайте суть принципа:

**Я попытаюсь наметить ряд основных принципов.**

**1. Тезис.**

**2. Тезис.**

**3. Тезис. Этот принцип...**

Если же вы именуете принципы порядковыми числительными, то тогда оформляйте их суть тоже более строго, используя одинаковые синтаксические конструкции перед подробным изложением сути принципа, например:

**Первый принцип. Положение... (тезис)**

**Второй принцип. ... (тезис)**

**Третий принцип. Связан с предыдущим и как бы вытекает из него...**